# Trying to downcast with polymorphism, what's going wrong?

Tags: c++

I have two pointers to a base class, one points to an actual base object and the other to a derived object. I also have a nonmember function that is overloaded for the base and derived classes. I'd like to use polymorphism to downcast the pointers so that the correct overload is called.

The output of the code is

```
base downcast called
base
derived downcast called
base
```

however the desired output is

```
base
derived
```

Can someone explain the output, and what must be done to get the desired behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
  virtual base& downcast()
  {
    cout << "base downcast called" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
  virtual derived& downcast()
  {
    cout << "derived downcast called" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
};

void foo(const base& a)
{
  cout << "base" << endl;
}

void foo(const derived& a)
{
  cout << "derived" << endl;
}


int main()
{
  base* ptr1 = new(base);
  base* ptr2 = new(derived);

  foo(ptr1->downcast());
  foo(ptr2->downcast());

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: added cout to the downcast functions to illustrate function override/polymorphism.

Comment: @tkausl - it very definitely should override the base's version.  The issue OP is having is not that they're hiding/overloading rather than overriding...but that the compiler sees the base's version of the function and its return type.

Comment: @tkausl Yes, it does override it. The demo, for you, is [here](https://ideone.com/jSqb17). The real reason, is the function calls are resolved at compile time, and not at run-time. And `ptr2` is of type `base*`, and `base::downcast` returns `base&`, so the `void foo(const base& a)` is called.

Comment: Won't work. You may want to make `foo` a virtual member function, or use the Visitor pattern.

Comment: Where do you think the polymorphism is here? You're not calling a `virtual` function.

Comment: Might be similar to [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B)

Comment: polymorphism occurs during the downcast call on ptr2.

Comment: As for explanation: you do undersand what `foo(ptr2)` would print and why, right? Now `ptr2->downcast()` has **the same type and value** as `ptr2`.

Comment: @n.m. I understand that in terms of compile time knowledge, as the compiler must decide on which foo variant to use before it knows which downcast variant will be used. However, even when returning *dyanmaic_cast(this) in the derived downcast the above behavior is observed. At this stage I'm surprised it's not a runtime error.

Comment: Now this is fully unexpected. Why on earth should it be a runtime error? What exactly is invalid?

Comment: From @AnT the overload for foo is determined at compile time to be void foo(const& base) in both calls, but it ends up getting a derived type. I guess that's fine for inheritance, but how the compiler picks which foo overload to use puzzles me.

Comment: It picks overloads based on **static types** of function arguments. What is the static type of `ptr2->downcast()`? Why?

Comment: It must be base, why it's base I'm not sure. When working with virtual functions, is the static type always the type returned by the base declaration?

Comment: Let's analyse:: what's the static type of `ptr2`? (Look at its declaration). Write it down. Based on *that*, what static type does `downcast` return? (Look at *its* declaration in the class you just wrote down).

Comment: I see, it's not about virtual, ptr2 is a base pointer so the static type of ptr2->downcast() is also base, regardless of the virtual attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically trying to make run-time polymorphism to affect compile-time overload resolution. This is not possible for obvious reasons. Function overloading is a compile-time feature, meaning that overload resolution is performed at compile time based on *static* types of function arguments.

In your case the choice of which `foo` to call is based on *static* typization: on *static* types of `ptr1` and `ptr2` and on *static* types of `ptr1->downcast()` and `ptr2->downcast()` return values. The latter are lvalues (references) of type `base` in both cases. There's no polymorphism involved in choosing `foo`. The compiler does not know (and does not care) that at run-time one of these `base &` references will actually refer to a `derived` object.

However, if you could call `a.downcast()` from `foo`, you would observe that rum-time polymorphism still works from inside `foo`. (At this time such call is not possible due to `downcast()` being non-const)

Comment: There is polymorphism as the derived downcast function is called, but i see what you're saying about the compile time overload resolution.

Comment: why is the static type of ptr2->downcast() base? Is it always the return type of the base function when virtual functions are used? I know it's not valid because it takes into account runtime knowledge, but the typeid from the type_info library tells me it returns a derived object.

Comment: @roro: "Static type" is *declared* type. `ptr2` is declared as `base *` in your example. So `ptr2->downcast()` is `base::downcast()`. And  `base::downcast()` is declared with return type `base &`. So, from static point of view, `ptr2->downcast()` is an lvalue of type `base`. And overload resolution is based entirely on static types. Meanwhile, `typeid` is a *run-time* feature - for polymorphic objects it returns their *dynamic* type. `typeid` tells you that `ptr2->downcast()` returns a `base &` reference that happens to be bound to `derived` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic_cast.  What you're trying to do won't work.

C++ allows covariant return values on *overridden* functions.  Since `derived` inherits from `base` it qualifies.  But if you call the base's version of the function you still get the type IT returns, not the derived class's version.  To get that return type you must have already casted so that the *compiler* knows what type the function returns.

Comment: It actually could work with `boost::variant`, but that is another story

Comment: It isn't clear what "you need dynamic_cast" might mean. Got working code?

Comment: @n.m.  Something like `if (auto pD = dynamic_cast<derived*>(ptr2)) foo(pD); else foo(ptr2);`.  (but I wouldn't write it as a one-liner like that)

Answer (score 0):

So we can do this in a somewhat generic way.

```
template<class...>struct types{};

template<std::size_t I>using index=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

template<class T, class types>
struct get_index_of_type;
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct get_index_of_type<T, types<T,Ts...>>:
  index<0>
{};
template<class T, class U, class...Ts>
struct get_index_of_type<T, types<U,Ts...>>:
  index<get_index_of_type<T, types<Ts...>>{}+1>
{};

template<class R, class Types>
struct dynamic_dispatch;
template<class R, class...Ts>
struct dynamic_dispatch<R, types<Ts...>>
{
  using fptr = R(*)(void const* pf, void* t);

  template<class F>
  std::array<fptr, sizeof...(Ts)>
  make_table() const {
    return {{
      +[](void const* pf, void* t)->R{
        auto* pt = static_cast< std::remove_reference_t<Ts>* >(t);
        auto* f = static_cast< std::remove_reference_t<F> const* >(pf);
        return (*f)(static_cast<Ts&&>(*pt));
      }...
    }};
  }
  void const* pf = nullptr; 
  std::array<fptr, sizeof...(Ts)> table;

  dynamic_dispatch( dynamic_dispatch&& )=default;
  dynamic_dispatch( dynamic_dispatch const& )=default;
  dynamic_dispatch& operator=( dynamic_dispatch&& )=default;
  dynamic_dispatch& operator=( dynamic_dispatch const& )=default;

  template<class F,
    std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, dynamic_dispatch>{}, int> =0
  >
  dynamic_dispatch( F&& f ):
    pf(std::addressof(f)),
    table( make_table<std::decay_t<F>>() )
  {}

  template<class T>
  R operator()( T&& t ) const {
    return table[get_index_of_type<T,types<Ts...>>{}]( pf, std::addressof(t) );
  }
};
```

`dynamic_dispatch<R, types<a,b,c>>` takes any callable that can be invoked with any of `a`, `b` or `c` (exactly type, including l/r value and const required, so make your list verbose.  No implicit casts are done; this can be fixed with more work).

Now, add a method in `base` called `apply`:

```
virtual void apply( dynamic_dispatch<void, types<base*, derived*>> f ) {
  return f(this);
}
```

override it in derived:

```
virtual void apply( dynamic_dispatch<void, types<base*, derived*>> f ) override {
  return f(this);
}
```

with the same body.

Now in main:

```
auto super_foo = [](auto* x) {
  return foo(*x);
};

int main()
{
  base* ptr1 = new(base);
  base* ptr2 = new(derived);

  ptr1->apply(super_foo);
  ptr2->apply(super_foo);
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f56e8aea74e8bb6).

For further reading, I type erased dynamic dispatch to a list of types on a function object.  I created a view to this dispatch.

`super_foo` is a single object representing the entire overload set of `foo`, permitting it to be passed as one parameter.

This can also be done more conventionally with a visitor pattern:

```
struct visitor {
  void invoke( base* ) const = 0;
  void invoke( derived* ) const = 0;
};
```

then you implement a `foo_visitor`:

```
struct foo_visitor:visitor {
  void invoke( base* a ) const {return foo(*a);}
  void invoke( derived* a ) const {return foo(*a);}
};
```

and we write an `apply` that takes a `visitor&` and does `.invoke(this)` on it.

Note that this technique, especially if you make it smartly choose between the `Ts` instead of requiring exact match, allows multiple dispatch polymorphism through recursion (or, you could change the `dynamic_dispatch` to `dynamic_dispatch< R, types... >` with multiple type packs).